# How to copy string code with escape sequences as a string that looks the same but the escape clauses act like how they look

Tags: arrays, c, string, escaping, character

Lets say we are given a string in code as such,

char* password = "this\nis\myPassword"

and I need to copy this string into a text file, but instead of appearing in the file as such;

---

this

is\myPassword

---

I would like it to appear in the file like the following

---

this\nis\myPassword

---

I have tried a few things, and the best solution I could think of was creating a character array with all the possible escape sequences

And if I loop through the original string and reach one character that is also in the created array I would enter another for loop modifying the string.

[Created Array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZgVj.png)

[The Actual Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ase3.png)

Now the problem I am stuck on is how can I chance the next digit in the string to be the second digit of the escape sequence

ie:
for \n:
I want to essentially modify it into 2 chars, '\' and 'n'
so It appears as "\n"

I can already tell my solution is very poor and can be improved drastically so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To do that you essentially have to locate each appearance of `\n` and replace it with `\\n`. In C there isn't a `replace` or equivalent function because string sizes are fixed. I will attempt to do something with similar functionality. So first let's try to get the size of the final string. To do that we need to count how many characters we have to replace. This function counts how many new line characters are in a string.

```
int countNewlines(char *str)
{
    int i = 0;
    while(*str != '\0')
        if(*str++ == '\n') i++;
    return i;
}
```

Now we will replace each of these with `\\n` which is in total two bytes, so the final length of the string will be

```
int length = strlen(str) + countNewlines(str);
```

Once we have this length we need to find each instance of `\n` and replace it with `\\n`, so let's loop over the string and create our final string.

```
char finalStr[length + 1]; // Plus one for the null terminator
for(int i = 0, j = 0; i < length + 1; i++, j++)
{
    if(str[i] == '\n')
    {
        finalStr[j++] = '\\';
        finalStr[j] = 'n';
    }
    else
    {
        finalStr[j] = str[i];
    }    
}
finalStr[length] = '\0'; // explicitly add the null terminator just in case.
printf("%s", finalStr);
```

Demo:

When we input `"Hello\n World\n!\n"`, the result in the console is

```
Hello\n World\n!\n
```

As can be seen, all newlines are replaced with their two-byte counterpart

You should be able to change this code and use it as you like.

Comment: I saw  you used a while loop with ‘\0’… I get why you did that but what if we want to have the \0 included in the answer aswell. Like let’s say the bull is included somewhere in the middle of the string and we need that to be printed as \0. This also goes for any exclusion statement. From what I know there is 15 of them. So would the only option be to do what I did in the pictures and create an array with all of them?

Comment: @SahirSood I see your point, the thing is you cannot print ```\0``` because there can never be a null in the middle of a string, null is always at the end. About the other terminating characters, you can adapt the function I wrote that counts them to count all of them, and the replacer function to replace all of them. If you cannot manage that just let me know and I will help you with that as well